# useEffect called in higher order component

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

After an update, React no longer compiles code with `useEffect` hooks in Higher Order Components (HOC). I have a HOC that connects to the Redux store and dispatches an action to fetch data if needed.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types' 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import SpinCenter from '../components/SpinCenter'
import { fetchObject } from '../actions/objects'
import { fetchIfNeeded } from '../utils'


const withObject = ({element}) => WrappedComponent => ({id, ...rest}) => {
  const hoc = ({status, object, fetchObject}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchIfNeeded(
        status,
        ()=>fetchObject(element, id),
      )
    })

    // Initial loading and error
    if (status === undefined || object === undefined) return <SpinCenter/>
    if (status.error) return <>error loading: {status.error.message}</>

    // Pass through the id for immediate access
    return <WrappedComponent {...{object, status, id}} {...rest} />
  }

  hoc.propTypes = {
    object: PropTypes.object,
    status: PropTypes.object,
    fetchObject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    object: state.data[element][id],
    status: state.objects[element][id]
  })

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchObject
  }

  const WithConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(hoc)
  return <WithConnect/>
}

export default withObject
```

I hope this makes sense. I guess the best approach would be to somehow place the `useEffect` into a functional component, but it is getting a bit complicated where this all should happen. Can anyone help me make sense of this?

This is the error I am getting.

```
React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "hoc" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component name need to start with an upper case character which is why you get this issue. Also you can optimise the connect and hoc code to return an instance of hoc once instead of doing it again and again

```
const withObject = ({element}) => WrappedComponent => {
  const Hoc = ({id, status, object, fetchObject,...rest}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchIfNeeded(
        status,
        ()=>fetchObject(element, id),
      )
    })

    // Initial loading and error
    if (status === undefined || object === undefined) return <SpinCenter/>
    if (status.error) return <>error loading: {status.error.message}</>

    // Pass through the id for immediate access
    return <WrappedComponent {...{object, status, id}} {...rest} />
  }

  Hoc.propTypes = {
    object: PropTypes.object,
    status: PropTypes.object,
    fetchObject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    object: state.data[element][id],
    status: state.objects[element][id]
  })

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchObject
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hoc)
}

export default withObject
```

Comment: Oh man, that was actually it. Well spotted. That is a bit harsh from the side of React.

Comment: Yeah it is harsh from the compiler. Also look at the updated answer. It might be helpful from performance point of view

Comment: Your updated answer was my first approach as well, but it returns an object rather than a React component and gives me: `Objects are not valid as a React child` when using it.

Comment: When using it you would create a component like

`const Wrap = withObject({})(WrappedComponent);`

and then use it in your React component like `<Wrap />` Not that you shouldn't create an instance within the component but outside of it

Comment: I think that is exactly what I am doing, but things become a bit hard to vary in an existing code base. I will try and demonstrate in a dedicated codesandbox. Thanks so far.